# Rounded corner transparent gradient Android glitch

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a RecyclerView with items containing ImageViews, over which i want to display a gradient shadow. To show some text. I have tried with a View with a drawable shape with rounded corners, i tried with ShapeableImageView, i have tried with cardviews. they all result in the same strange graphic glitch where the corners are discolored.

this is my view drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_corner_radius" />
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/card_shadow_bottom"
        android:startColor="@color/card_shadow_top"
        android:angle="270"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

this is my item layout

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                imageUrl="@{obj.imageUrl}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_image_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_card_shadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/card_shadow"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_image"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_image" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the result:
[image: and this is the result]

What is causing it? how can i fix it?

Comment: Check this issue. It seems very similar: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/881#issuecomment-571771871

Comment: Thanks, indeed it seems similar. The proposed solutions did not work for me though